# Mackey theory application - semidirect product abelian-by-finite

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, induced-representations

In order to advance my research I'm supposed to understand this fact:

Let $A$ be an abelian group and $S$ a finite group acting on $A$.
This defines the semi-direct product $A\rtimes S$:

Let $\chi$ be a character of $A$.
Define $S_\chi = \{s\in S \mid s\chi = \chi\}$
(Recall: $s\chi = \chi \iff \forall a\in A, \chi(sas^{-1}) = \chi(a)$ ).

Note this defines a subgroup of $A \rtimes S> A \rtimes S_\chi$

We can extend each representation of $A$ to a representation of $A \rtimes S_\chi$ by:
  $\chi: A \rightarrow \mathbb{C}, \chi(as) := \chi(a)$.

Let $(\sigma,V) \in Irr (S_\chi)$.
        Note $\chi \otimes \sigma $ is a representation of $A \rtimes S_\chi$.
        Then:

1. $Ind_{A \rtimes S_\chi}^{A \rtimes S} \chi \otimes \sigma$ is irreducible
2. For any irreducible representation of $A \rtimes S$, there are $\chi \in Irr(A)$ and $\sigma \in Irr(S_{\chi})$ s.t. the representation is:
           $Ind_{A \rtimes S_\chi}^{A \rtimes S} \chi \otimes \sigma$

If I understand correctly the proof of this statement should be straight forward from Mackey theory, but I can't see the picture.
My instructor calls this statement Mackey theory - which is different from the statement I see in other textbooks (seems like this is an application - correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: I think you understand correctly, I find the “pedagogical” Chap. XII.1 of [Fell-Doran](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=90c:46002) (*The Mackey Normal Subgroup Analysis for Finite Groups*) a good place to see all statements and proofs in just about your desired generality (semidirect product simplifications in section 1.12).

Comment: Instead of Mackey, look for Clifford Theory. One possible reference is:
G. Karpilovsky, Group Representations, Vol. 2, North-Holland Mathematics Studies,
Volume 177 (North-Holland Publishing Company, Amsterdam, 1993).
You can also look at the paper by Crisp, Onn and me,
https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.04486, the beginning of Section 3

Comment: I have found the specific solution at: Linear· Representations
of Finite Groups Serre, 8.2 Semidirect products by an abelian group